# stack raster images from a folder in R

Tags: r, raster

```
library(raster)
img <- list.files(pattern='*.img')
stack <- stack(img)
```

The code above should work but despite having *.img files in my folder, I also have *img.xml and *img.aux.xml files. How do I rewrite my code so that it only stack *.img files?

Comment: Probably best not to call your object by the same name as the function that creates it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will only match files that end with `img`.

```
library(raster)
img <- list.files(pattern='\\.img$')
stack <- stack(img)
```

Note the `$` at the end, this signifies `ends with`.

Comment: But you shouldn't need the `*`?

Comment: I removed the `*`, but also escaped the `.` to ensure it only matches `.img` (i.e. the extension of the file).

Answer (score 2):

The `pattern` argument is a regular expression. It looks like you only want files that end in `.img`, so adding a `$` (end of string anchor) should do the trick.

```
img <- list.files(pattern='\\.img$')
```